# Copy a mp4 stream with InputStream and OutputStream

Tags: java, android, video, mp4

I have a mp4 file which I want to copy.

```
byte buffer = new byte[1024];
inputStream = new FileInputStream(Mp4FileIN);
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(Mp4fileOUT);

int length;             
while((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
      fileOutStream.write(buffer, 0, length);           

 fileOutStream.close();
```

Bytes of the output file are exactly the same of the original, but clearly it is not the same file.

Why I can't play it?

What is wrong in this approach?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I've just realized, that after some attemps, sometimes it works, sometime it doesn't.
So my question is the same, what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: You could use the diff command from a terminal to see if the files are exactly the same.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace/error logging you get when you try to play the copied version?

Comment: just edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: Have you got the same file extension? It should be `foo.mp4`, `foo.m4a` or `foo.m4p`. You can use the file command to tell you what type of file the computer thinks it is `file foo.mp4`.

Comment: The file extension is the same, yes